# Roll rows with variable step value on a 2D tensor

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I have a tensor `a` that I would like to first mask using `mask` and then discard the remaining frames. To ensure the output tensor is of the correct shape, padding should fill in the remaining values at the end. I can assume there is only a single continuous sequence of `True`'s in each row of the mask.

e.g.

```
a = torch.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)
# tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
#         [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
#         [13, 14, 15, 16]])

mask = torch.tensor([[False,  True,  True, False],
                     [False,  True,  True,  True],
                     [ True, False, False, False],
                     [ True,  True,  True,  True]])

# desired output (assuming padding value is 0):
# tensor([[ 2,  3,  0,  0],
#         [ 6,  7,  8,  0],
#         [ 9,  0,  0,  0],
#         [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

I can achieve the desired output by applying [`torch.masked_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html) followed by [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html) on each row in a loop but I am struggling to think of a way to do this more efficiently in batches.

I have also looked into starting by using [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.roll.html) and zeroing after appropriate indexes, but this function can only be applied across an entire dimension and not a custom amount of roll per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By applying [`torch.sort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html) on the mask itself you can achieve the desired result. Indeed if your sort the boolean values you can manage to move the `False` values at the end of the stack, and let the `True` values at the beginning.

<s>Do note this might vary depending on the sorting algorithm, there might be some shuffling for certain algorithms...</s>. As [@Seraf Fej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7520067/seraf-fej) pointed out: you can use the `stable=True` option on `torch.stable` such that the order of equivalent items is preserved.

Then use the indices of the sorting to gather the values on `a` with [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). Finally, you will need to mask the resulting matrix to replace the discarded values with the appropriate padding.

```
>>> a
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])

>>> mask
tensor([[False,  True,  True, False],
        [False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Sort the mask:

```
>>> values, indices = mask.sort(1, descending=True, stable=True)

>>> values
tensor([[ True,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]])

>>> indices
tensor([[1, 2, 0, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Gather from `indices` and mask with `values`:

```
>>> a.gather(1, indices)*values
tensor([[ 2,  3,  0,  0],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  0],
        [ 9,  0,  0,  0],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

---

You can easily extend to any padding value using [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html):

```
>>> torch.where(values, a.gather(1, indices), -1)
tensor([[ 2,  3, -1, -1],
        [ 6,  7,  8, -1],
        [ 9, -1, -1, -1],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Or using the inverse mask `~values`, weighted by the padding value:

```
>>> a.gather(1, indices)*values -1*~values
tensor([[ 2,  3, -1, -1],
        [ 6,  7,  8, -1],
        [ 9, -1, -1, -1],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Thanks, clever solution! I notice `torch.sort` takes the argument `stable=True` which preserves the order of equivalent elements. So I think using `values, indices = torch.sort(mask, dim=1, descending=True, stable=True)` should account for the potential shuffling issue you mentioned.